# Failed prop type: Component: prop type `props` is invalid;

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-proptypes

I am getting warning as" Warning: Failed prop type: Component: prop type `props` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `object`"

my code is:

```
  const { history } = props.props
history.push('/next');

Component.propTypes = {
    props: {
        history: PropTypes.object,
    },
}

Component.defaultProps = {
    props: {
        history: PropTypes.object,
    },
}
```

My functionality working fine but getting this console error Can someone help me to resolve this warning?

Comment: `props.props` seems a little confusing. Is there a way you could simply send the history as `props.history` or is this some pattern that I am unaware of? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're using the value `{}` for `props` in `propTypes`, that's not allowed.  You want `shape`:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.shape({
    history: PropTypes.object,
  }),
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I add .isRequired, warning is showing as "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `props` is marked as required in `Component`, but its value is `undefined`".

Comment: Then that value isn't defined somewhere, probably on an initial render, if all your functionality is there.